# Nouns where the negative demands a different verb

Tags: negation

We learned

> 我對什麼什麼很感興趣

But when I wrote

> xx我對明星一點興趣都不感

It was corrected to

> 我對明星一點興趣都沒有

What are some other nouns that take a different verb in the negative?

Comment: see bkrs for examples of 不感兴趣：他对音乐不感兴趣，对...不感兴趣, also see example with 一点儿不感(到):但是目前他对她们不忠,他却一点儿不感到内疚.

Comment: @user6065 does this suggest the correction was unnecessary?

Comment: 我對明星一點興趣都不感 --> 我對明星一點都不感興趣

Comment: examples with 一点儿+NP＋也（都） **没有**  :一点儿用处也没有 utterly useless 一点儿才能也没有,一点儿胃口也没有,一点儿坏处也没有,他一点儿筋骨囊也没有，一丁点儿毛病都没有，

Comment: Think of 感兴趣 as an indivisible verb, rather than a V(感)+O(兴趣) phrase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 我對明星一點興趣都不感

Your problem is not that verb itself, but the word order. 
The correct order is: 我對明星一點 都不感興趣.

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can often split up verbs and nouns, there are some which feel awkward when you do it. 感兴趣 is one of them. Even though 感 is a verb and 兴趣 is a noun, it doesn't feel right to say 一点兴趣都不感. The normal way to say it is 一点都不感兴趣. As for "why?" I've no idea.

I also can't think of any nouns that demand a different verb in the negative.

Comment: can you think of more un splittable examples?